# Facebook link in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I want to give the user a link to my app's Facebook page so the user can like it. I don't want there to be any login, permissions or any other social functionality. I thought I could use a simple link like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/MyAppPage")!)
```

I thought this would take the user to the Facebook app and open my app's page, or if the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed, take them to Safari. It did go to the Facebook app, but didn't go to my page. Is there a simple way to do this? Do I need to implement the Facebook SDK or Social Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I use. Your app will have two links, one for the FB app and one for the browser. This will check to see if the device supports the FB app link first and if not show it in the browser (if available).

```
let urls = ["fb://profile/xxxxxxxx",
    "https://m.facebook.com/xxxxxxx"];

let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

for urlString in urls {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    if(application.canOpenURL(url!))
    {
        application.openURL(url!)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: I had also been using my page's name and not the id number.